Read data from the table, find the necessary user variable, and display it on the screen. ClosedXML
I'm still quite new to programming and I started with C#. I want to make a simple application that accepts an error number from the user, for example: "F_220". Read data from the table, find this place in the table and use columns and rows to provide an explanation for this error. For example, there is a table with cells: B:13 - "F_220" and C:13 - "Error, do something". I found ClosedXML in. If this is a good tool, please help, if not, what can be used?
I understand that this is the wrong code
private void Excel()
{
    using var workbook = new XLWorkbook("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\VSC-500.xlsx");
    var ws1 = workbook.Worksheet(1);
    string error = textBox1.Text;


    var rowCount = workbook.Worksheet(1).LastRowUsed().RowNumber();
    var columnCount = workbook.Worksheet(1).LastColumnUsed().ColumnNumber();
    int column = 1;
    int row = 1;
    List<string> ll = new List<string>();
    while (row <= rowCount)
    {
        while (column <= columnCount)
        {
            string title = workbook.Worksheets.Worksheet(1).Cell(row, column).GetString();
            ll.Add(title);
            column++;  
        }
        row++;
        column = 1;
    }
    var container = ll.FindAll(s => s.Contains(error));
    var str = string.Join(",", ll);
    MessageBox.Show(str);```


What about index() with match() in Excel: index(col_with_error_detail,match(error_code,col_with_error_codes,0)
